# External USB drive not shown in lsusb

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I have found many issues where the driver was found by sudo lsusb -v but not mounted. However that is NOT my problem.

NOTE It DOES detect and automounts my USB memory sticks. That works with no problem.

What doesn't work is my external shintaro USB drive.
NOTE This drive DOES mount and work on host OS which is win7 64bit.

However when I mount it on the VM, nothing. 
I do get the following diff from "sudo lsusb -v":

```
14c14
<   iManufacturer           3 (error)
---
>   iManufacturer           3 Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ehci_hcd
61c61
<    Port 1: 0000.0501 highspeed power connect
---
>    Port 1: 0000.0100 power
```

I have installed "Ubuntu 14.04.1 64bit desktop LTS" in "Oracle VM VirtualBox Version 4.3.20 r96997".

I have also installed "VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.20_96996".

I'm not sure where to look to go to the next level of debugging.
All help is welcome.

Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to enable USB 2.0  as in this photo

[image]

Comment: Hi Fat Mind, thanks for your reply. Yes both boxes are ticked.